# How do I set up a custom target triplet for Rust, using JSON?

Tags: json, rust, llvm, cross-compiling

I have done cross compilation with Rust before, but [where I got the JSON](https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/#putting-it-together) didn't explain anything about creating one outside of what we need to change from the x86_64 Linux target, but I need an avr8 target. This requires rewriting most of the file.

That blog post is all I know about cross-compilation with Rust, but I have setup GCC cross compilers.

Comment: Some cursory internet searches for ["avr rust"](https://www.google.com/search?q=avr+rust) lead to the [AVR Rust project](https://github.com/avr-rust/), where you will learn that *Rust doesn't support AVR yet*. Clicking through the READMEs (which you should read) will get you to [one of many possible JSON target files](https://github.com/avr-rust/blink/blob/master/avr-atmega328p.json)

Comment: I've actually seen that project, but I didn't see the JSON file, thanks for that. I still would like to know how the formatting works, but I will look at this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can find JSON file where you can put multiple configuration to create you custom target triple: https://book.avr-rust.com/005.1-the-target-specification-json-file.html
And if you still need to understand some basic details then you can refer to this tutorial as well: https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/#target-specification

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: If linking to a file in the web is the only possible answer to this question, then the question would be off-topic for asking for a reference to a resource, i.e. it would be flaggable as "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more".